# To get the row number in JTable where the string will match over first column in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Consider their is an JTable as...

```
SrNo.     Name      City
1         John      NY
2         Mohit     CA
3         Jay       AZ
```

If I pass the function `String` "Mohit" then it should `return` the `rowIndex` where it will match the `string`.
As here the function should return `rowIndex` as `1`. (Have to find only over `columnIndex(1)`)

Answer (score 2):

You could use getValueAt and iterate over the table till you hit an equal value.

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
```

Comment: But if their are lots of entries in JTable this method will increase the number of iterations.

Comment: However, it is as far as I know the only possibility.

Comment: 1+, @AshwinK yes you need to iterate until you find a match.